# Why will the green rectangle showing rep increase not disappear?

Tags: bug, reputation, notifications

As most of you know, when you gain rep, you see a small green rectangle at the top of the page showing how much rep you earned.

[image: Rep increase]

---

Usually I can make it disappear by clicking on it twice. I clicked on it twice, and it faded from view. However, when I click on a new question, that green bar is there once again. It's still there as I type! I tried clicking on the answers that were upvoted, but that did not solve the problem. Is there a way to fix this?

**Related Meta.SE Thread:** [Added rep notification isn't going away after clicking it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233447/added-rep-notification-isnt-going-away-after-clicking-it)

Comment: Also here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13873/persistent-comment

Comment: Seems like fallout from the datacenter move (other sites are still readonly or offline.). Chances are it will be fixed in not too long.

Comment: Is solved for me. (I assume generally.)